# Change pointer addres to another object

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I have two instances of two different classes which are derived from the same abstract base class. And I have a pointer to one of these instances. How can I use the same pointer to point on another instance?

Comment: Why can't you just `ptr = &obj1;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the pointer a `Base` pointer:

```
class Base {
    // ...
}

class Derived1 : public Base {
    // ...
}


class Derived2 : public Base {
    // ...
}

Base* bp = new Derived1();
    // ... delete or store Derived1 object
bp = new Derived2();
```

obviously raw pointers are used for simplicity, use smart pointers in your code.